# How to toggle automatic formatting with a single keybind in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to toggle automatic formatting in vim (e.g. enable with `fo+=a` if not enabled, disable with `fo-=a` otherwise) with a single keybind like so:

```
nnoremap <leader>a "magic goes here"
```

I thought about using some exists check with conditionals but I couldn't find any. How can I do this?

Comment: Whoa. People, vim questions belong on SO. Especially the ones which talk about scripting it, obviously. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I'd do:

```
function! ToggleAutoFormat()
    if -1==stdridx(&fo, 'a')
        set fo+=a
    else
        set fo-=a
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>a :call ToggleAutoFormat()
```

Comment: Ooh, one liner: `nnoremap <leader>a :exe 'set fo'.(&fo=~'a'?'-':'+').'=a'<CR>`

Comment: @Daan kudos! I didn't have the `=~` operator memorized! I did a similar oneliner trick with dual bool settings here http://superuser.com/a/339595/75721 in case you're interested :)

Comment: Wow.  I had forgotten about conditionals.  Very elegant.

Answer (score 3):

The magic is the '&' in the snippet below

:help expr-option

```
nnoremap <leader>a call ToggleFormat()

function! toggleFormat()
      if &formatoptions !~ 'a'
          set fo+=a
      else
          set fo-=a
      endif
  return 0 
endfunction
```

Comment: +1 for the cleaner `!~` version of sehe's answer. it's funny you use `formatoptions` in the conditional and `fo` inside. btw what does `return 0` do?

Comment: return 0 does nothing in this context.  However, you could put returns in the various conditions and interpret the status result for other purposes (for example returning 1 in the top for 'I turned it on').  Including it as I have Is just a habit I have to make this function a pseudo-procedure.

Comment: Note: The function name should be `ToggleFormat`, not `toggleFormat`. Also, the `nnoremap` should use `:call`, not `call`. The `nnoremap` as currently defined will prepare the ToggleFormat function for execution from the command bar, but won't actually execute it. Add `<CR>` to the end to automatically execute the function when you press `<leader>a`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated version of Lighthart's answer, incorporating a few tweaks:

```
function! ToggleFormat()
      if &formatoptions !~ 'a'
          set fo+=a
      else
          set fo-=a
      endif
      "" print the value of formatoptions once we're done
      set formatoptions
endfunction

"" End with <CR> to instantly run the function when triggered.
nnoremap <leader>a :call ToggleFormat()<CR>
```